# kustomize suffix hashes on only certain items

Tags: suffix, kustomize

i have a kustomize environment where there are certain configMaps and secrets that i do want to be "version controlled" and have the suffix hash appended to them. however, i *also* would like certain `configMapGenerator` items that should *not* have the suffix hash. can i mix and match?

specifically, the general syntax to exclude all suffix hashes is

```
generatorOptions:
  disableNameSuffixHash: true
```

is there a some special syntax i can add to

```
configMapGenerator:
- name: my-config-with-suffix-hash
  files:
  - file1.txt
- name: my-other-config-without-suffix-hash
  files:
  - files2.txt
```

thanks!

Comment: tried the same as yee379, seems ```disableNameSuffixHash: true``` has no effect in ```Version:kustomize/v4.1.2```

Comment: You can add "options:" at the same level as "name:"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as per @user1170291's comment, the solution is

```
configMapGenerator:
- name: my-config-with-suffix-hash
  files:
  - file1.txt
- name: my-other-config-without-suffix-hash
  options:
    disableNameSuffixHash: true
  files:
  - files2.txt
```